# Add Custom field in Only Billing Address form not in Shipping Address form

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, billing, customer-address, customer-attribute

I want to create an attribute only for billing address form, I was study the following tutorial

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend

In the above link I have successfully create an attribute name as **jobtitle** ,  when I try to remove **jobtitle** from shipping address form, the form are not save. Please anyone help me. How to solve this?? Please guide me.

Comment: did you check the following third party extension for checkout fields, it allows you to add, remove, resize custom feilds on billing, checkout pages and set the position as required, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/additional-checkout-attributes-custom-fields-manager.html

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the tutorial my guess is that this attribute is set as required when creating the attribute in the setup script.

```
'is_required'       => 1,
```

In Magento an address is simply an address if it is a shipping or billing magento does not really care on the customer address level, so if this attribute is required you would need to add it to both the shipping and billing address forms.